# GoogleMaps GroundOverlay blinks my images

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

I'm using GoogleMaps in my Android app, and I want to display an animated radar image on the map.
I have an array of 6 Bitmaps. When the user hits play, the map loops through displaying each of those images on the map.

This is working, but when transitioning between the images, if I don't call `GoogleMap.clear()`, the images just get continually stacked on top of each other.
If I do call `GoogleMap.clear()`, I get a horrible blink. I want one image to remain on the map until the next one is displayed.
Is there a good way to do this?

Is there maybe a double-buffering option for GoogleMaps?

Comment: Did you find solution to you problem?I am also looking for the same thing in my app.

Comment: I hate the solution I used, but my co-workers think it's good enough.

As it turns out, the problem only exists when the bitmaps are too big to process quickly (mine are 1200x1200). Besides that, the app would run out of memory and crash if you zoomed too close.

In the end I stopped using the GoogleMap GroundOverlay altogether, and instead I use an ImageView on top of the GoogleMap. I use GoogleMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation() to determine where the bounds of the image should be.

Comment: Are you still using GoogleMap.Clear() which transitioning between images or something else?

Comment: Well, I'm never using GroundOverlay at all, so there is nothing to clear on the GoogleMap.

Comment: Would it be crazy to use an animated .gif instead?


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603383/google-maps-js-api-v3-and-looping-animated-gifs

Comment: I worked a bit with google maps and what I did to increase the speed was to do all the processing on a background thread(handlerthread in my case) and all the UI stuff on the UI thread, like remove, add marker, etc. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, actually,  what I ended up doing was extending the GoogleMap class and overriding the onDraw function to my liking.