# Gmap Angularjs Gif Markers Doesn't Loop

Tags: java, html, angularjs, google-maps

I'm using gmap with angularjs. I have created one variable as json array for markers that includes id and coords like this:

```
{ "id": 1, "coords": { "latitude": 20 , "longitude": 30 } ,"icon": {"url": 'image.gif'}},
```

But the problem is gif marker icon doesn't loop. I've also tried with putting `optimized : false` but nothing changed. When I open panaroma view, the gif loops but on the normal map it doesn't loop. Could you help me how can I do this? Or any examples.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set [`optimized: false`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MarkerOptions), you can try the code sample in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603383/google-maps-js-api-v3-and-looping-animated-gifs).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Marker Simple</title>
    <link href="https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 4,
          center: myLatlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!',
            icon: "http://gwtportlets.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/src/org/gwtportlets/portlet/public/img/portlet-loading-32x32.gif",
          optimized: false
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas">

    </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can also check this related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979676/gif-marker-google-maps/5979869#5979869) that states that the markers use something called optimized rendering that always renders the markers as static. Check the sample code for generating the marker:

> ```
> var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>     position: latLng,
>     map: map,
>     icon: icon,
>     optimized: false
>   });
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have already seen this answer before but Im using ui-gmap-google-map , so codes are different, I dont use new google.maps.Marker so when i put optimized : false into the $scope.markers that doesnt work.. But thanks for helping